# Use variables in another section in Python ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser

I know I can use %(values)s to use the exist variable in the config file. But it seems that I can only use the variable in the same section. Is there any way to use the variable in other sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [extended interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation). This allows you to use the `${section:option}` syntax to refer to values from other sections.

Comment: It works quite well in python 3 but it doesn't work in python 2.

Comment: Oh, boo. This seems a suitable candidate for a backport, I don't see why it wouldn't work in Python 2. Sorry!